# Customer segments not working for multi store match customer according to condition in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

I am new in Magento. I have two stores Row and GB and requirement is we need to create customer segment in backend and we need Match customer according to below condition.

**Condition** : We need to found match zero order customers.
Like

**If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Total  Number of Orders is  0  while ALL  of these Conditions match:**

So Its working fine for individual store.

If I select **GB store** in general property and run the cron and refresh it's given correct results of match customer 5.

If I select **Row store** in general property and run the cron and refresh it's given correct results of match customer 6.

But when I select **both store** it's given only 6 records of match customer instead of 11 records match customer.

So fix the issue in below file and method though patch.

**vendor/magento/module-customer-segment/Model/ResourceModel/Customer/LinksMatcher.php**

```
private function matchCustomersByCondition(SegmentModel $segment): \Generator
    {
        $websiteIds = $segment->getWebsiteIds();
        foreach ($websiteIds as $websiteId) {
            $customerIds = $segment->getConditions()->getSatisfiedIds($websiteId);
            //get customers ids that satisfy conditions
            foreach ($customerIds as $customerId) {
                yield $customerId;
            }
           
            if ($this->configShare->isGlobalScope()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have comment below code in above method.

```
//if ($this->configShare->isGlobalScope()) {
    //   break;
//}
```

Then check with both selected store and run the cron Its given correct 11 match customer records.

But according to me it's not proper solution.

Please help for any official patch of Magento or any other solution if you have.